# iPhone/iTunes Connect - Is it possible to automatically create an app and fill in metadata for it?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I am wondering if it is possible to automatically do the following regarding the iPhone app store and iTunes connect:

1. Create an app id and bundle id.
2. Create provisioning profiles.
3. Create an app in iTunes connect and edit its metadata.
4. Upload screenshots and icons to an app.

I understand there is no API but is there any other alternative to doing this automatically? or at least doing one of these?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no other way to do it. Now with more recent XCode version, you can upload your application binary directly from XCode (no need to go on itunesconnect). But all other steps you mentioned still need to be done manually.